# Jersey client 1.17 PUT request returns Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length

Tags: azure, request, put, jersey-client, http-error

I am trying to create an empty PUT request in Jersey 1.17  to communicate to Azure Storage REST api like this

HTTPClient

```
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();

    config.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
            connectionTimeOut);
    config.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_READ_TIMEOUT,
            readTimeOut);

    Client client = Client.create(config);
    client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(
                    "https://" + accountName + "." + storageMedium + "."
                            + host)
                            .path(containerName)
            .queryParam("restype", "container");
```

PUT request

```
   //
    ClientResponse response = webResource
                    .header(Constants.X_MS_VERSION, "2015-02-21")
                    .header("x-ms-date", storage.date)
                    .header("Authorization", authorizationString).put(ClientResponse.class);
```

the response from Server is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I don't think the issue is with Azure REST api as a PUT request works in Postman. I don't know what is the issue with my Jersey client. Has someone ever come across a similar scenario?

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out what the issue was. In Jersey client to send an Empty body to a PUT request we need to set an Empty String as an entity to your client. For instance

```
resource.put(ClientResponse.class, "");
```

this will set Content-Length as 0 and Content-Type as "text/plain" in your http request.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why Azure API does not work equals.
It works in differents places.

**Examples:**

```
... post(String.class, "");
... post(String.class, "{}");
... post(String.class, new byte[]{});
```

also you can use **ClientResponse** class for processing response like **response.getStatus()**

```
ClientResponse response = ... post(ClientResponse.class, new byte[]{});
String ret = response.getEntity(String.class);
```